# Firebase Android: Child JSON array not being serialized properly on Android 4.2.2

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, firebase

I am serializing a Party object which looks like this:

```
public class Party {
    public long lastPing;
    public string id;
    public int ownerId;
    public List<PartyPlayer> players;
    public int status;
    public long created;
    public long lastServerUpdate;
    public int balance;
    public int size;
    public PartyCharacter character;
    public string mmcId;
}
```

Normally, a properly formatted JSON object would look like this (Look at the players object, it is a regular object array):

```
{"id":"key_test","players":[{"character":{"level":9,"visibleItems":[4,0,0],"id":970,"experience":54000,"type":1,"visibleSkills":[1,2,3]},"name":"wizard428","lastPing":1461555298086,"id":428}]}
```

However, when I run that same code on Android 4.2.2, the players object is not a valid JSON Array, instead, the array is serialized as a giant string:

```
{"id":"key_test","players":"[{id=467, lastPing=1461555567191, name=dragonfly467, character={id=1049, experience=0, visibleSkills=[1, 2, 3], level=1, visibleItems=[4, 0, 0], type=1}}]"}
```

Here's the C# wrapper that gets the value from firebase:

```
public string StringValue
{
    get 
    {
        AndroidJavaObject javaObject = getJavaObject ().Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getValue");
        return javaObject != null ? javaObject.Call<string> ("toString") : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

The code I'm using is super straight forward and looks like this:

```
public void AddOrUpdateParty(Dictionary<string,object> d) {
    string dSer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (d);
    Debug.Log ("Serialized object: " + dSer);
}
```

**Temporary workaround:**

I wrote a temporary workaround by creating the following methods that adds double quotes to any object that is supposed to be a string to make it parsable by Json.Net. If you're using this, just add your string values to the 3rd line in the string array.

```
class JsonEditor {
    public static String recursiveQuotes(string s) {
        string[] stringify = new string[]{ "id","name", "mmcId", "currentMatch"}; // we have to add the search terms because strings can contain int values and they are impossible to identify by checking the value.
        string searchTerm = null;
        foreach(string check in stringify) {
            if (s.Contains (check+"=")) { // we also replace = with :, so check+= is confirmation there are untouched strings.
                searchTerm = check;
            } 
        }
        if (searchTerm != null) {
            // find the search term and the value that follows it, then replace the value with string quotes

            string searchArea = s.Split(new string[]{searchTerm+"="}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
            string value = searchArea.Split (',') [0];
            if(value.Contains("}")) {
                value = searchArea.Split('}')[0];
            }
            string replaceTerm = searchTerm + "=" + value;
            string newTerm = searchTerm + ":\"" + value + "\"";
            s = s.Replace (replaceTerm, newTerm);
            return recursiveQuotes (s);
        } else {
            return s.Replace("=",":").Replace("\"[", "[").Replace("]\"", "]");
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Party> (JsonEditor.recursiveQuotes(d));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a chance you somehow have a `TypeConverter` installed for your `List<PartyPlayer>`?  What happens if you do [`TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(d.players, true)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7wd3zkh.aspx)?

Comment: @dbc do you mean TypeDescriptor.GetConverter (d["players"],  true); ?

Comment: d is a Dictionary in this case. I'll paste the whole function.

Comment: Can you show the JSON you are receiving from the server and how you are initially deserializing it to a dictionary?

Comment: @dbc did some digging, figured out there is some hidden underlying JSON library called MiniJSON doing the deserialization. Seems more likely the bug is occuring there. Will keep you posted.

Comment: @dbc turns out it's coming from this. Will have to do a work-around: AndroidJavaObject valueObject = getJavaObject ().Call<AndroidJavaObject> ("getValue");
   if (valueObject == null) 
   {
    return null;
   }
   AndroidJavaObject json = new AndroidJavaObject ("org.json.JSONObject", valueObject);